# GetRecord<T> returns null if a single reading exception occurs - CSVHelper library .NET

Tags: csvhelper

I am using the CSVHelper library for .NET
https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper

I have a class-map which looks as follows:

```
public class MyMap : ClassMap<Product>
{
    Map(c => c.DateVariable).Name("NonDateColumn");
    // Other valid map statements
}
```

When calling to get a record, if just a single map statement fails or has a type mismatch the row comes back as null.

```
var record = reader.GetRecord<T>();
```

I'm looking for whatever data was mapped successfully to come back, and the default values to be used for the rest of the record.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do that out of the box.  You could, however, create your own custom converters that return default values if they can't parse the data. For `DateTime`, I took the code from `DateTimeConverter` in the [GitHub project](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/blob/master/src/CsvHelper/TypeConversion/DateTimeConverter.cs) and modified it to return `DateTime.MinValue` if it couldn't parse the field.

```cs
public class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
        using (var writer = new StreamWriter(stream))
        using (var reader = new StreamReader(stream))
        using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
        {
            writer.WriteLine("Id,NonDateVariable,Bar");
            writer.WriteLine("1,Not a date,bar value");
            writer.WriteLine("2,2020/07/16,another value");
            writer.Flush();
            stream.Position = 0;

            csv.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.AddConverter<DateTime>(new BadDateConverter());
            csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<FooClassMap>();

            var records = csv.GetRecords<Foo>();
        }
    }
}

public class Foo
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime DateVariable { get; set; }
    public string Bar { get; set; }
}


public class FooClassMap : ClassMap<Foo>
{
    public FooClassMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id);
        Map(m => m.DateVariable).Name("NonDateVariable");
        Map(m => m.Bar);
    }
}

public class BadDateConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        if (text == null)
        {
            return base.ConvertFromString(null, row, memberMapData);
        }

        var formatProvider = (IFormatProvider)memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.CultureInfo.GetFormat(typeof(DateTimeFormatInfo)) ?? memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.CultureInfo;
        var dateTimeStyle = memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.DateTimeStyle ?? DateTimeStyles.None;

        if (memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.Formats == null || memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.Formats.Length == 0)
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParse(text, formatProvider, dateTimeStyle, out var d))
            {
                return d;
            }
            else
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (DateTime.TryParseExact(text, memberMapData.TypeConverterOptions.Formats, formatProvider, dateTimeStyle, out var d))
            {
                return d;
            }
            else
            {
                return DateTime.MinValue;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You could also create a wrapper converter to use on any field.

```cs
public class NullIfErrorConverter : DefaultTypeConverter
{
    public override object ConvertFromString(string text, IReaderRow row, MemberMapData memberMapData)
    {
        var type = 
            (memberMapData.Member as PropertyInfo)?.PropertyType ??
            (memberMapData.Member as FieldInfo)?.FieldType ??
            throw new InvalidOperationException($"Invalid member type. '{memberMapData.Member.MemberType}'");
            
        var typeConverter = row.Configuration.TypeConverterCache.GetConverter(type);
        memberMapData.TypeConverter = typeConverter;
        try 
        {
            return typeConverter.ConvertFromString(text, row, memberMapData);
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure you attach it to members in the mapping and not globally though, since it's using the global type cache.